# GTK+, g_convert() и недопустимое преобразование

Tags: c, windows, gtk, charset

В общем, ситуация такова.

Все происходит в **Windows 10**, я использую **gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()** для того, чтобы получить имя файла, который был выбран в диалоге выбора файла. Это имя представлено в виде **utf-8**.

Я хочу *скормить* это имя функции **fopen()**, которая в моем случае умеет обрабатывать только однобайтные символы. Я разобрался с тем, как использовать **g_convert()** и преобразовать строку из **utf-8** в строку однобайтовых символов в кодировке **CP1251** (**ascii** или **ansi**?).

Теперь **fopen()** может открывать файлы, выбранные в gtk-диалоге, даже если в пути/имени файлов будут встречаться кириллические символы...

Но если там окажутся иероглифы или другие символы, которые не могут быть представлены в **CP1251**, то **g_convert()** завершается ошибкой. В общем-то, это логично и правильно.

Вопросы такие:

1) Как при помощи **fopen()** открывать файлы, имена которых содержат *недопустимые* символы?

2) Я иногда полистывал Рихтера и, на сколько я помню, в ядре **Windows NT** везде используется юникод, а само **Win API** предоставляет пары функций - для юникода и для однобайтовых(?) строк. Причем, при использовании однобайтовой версии той или иной функции, строки все равно конвертируются в юникод перед использованием ядром. Ну и соответственно при выдаче юникод строк из ядра они конвертируются в однобайтовые, если используется версия функции для работы с однобайтовыми символами.

Все эти проблемы с кодировками и одно-дву-много байтовыми символами меня очень напрягают. Я просто не понимаю, что происходит.

Как имена файлов представлены в **Windows 10** на самом деле?

3) Даже если вместо **fopen()** использовать **Win API, CreateFile()**, то могут быть проблемы с открытием файла, в имени/пути которого имеются *недопустимые* символы.

Comment: В юникоде нету недопустимых символов. В Windows имена файлов представлены в UTF-16LE. Для открытия файлов используйте либо [CreateFileW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew), либо [`_wfopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx)

Comment: Указанные функции как раз и принимают строку в кодировке UTF-16. Вы бы сперва разобрались что к чему, прежде чем обзывать API костылём.

Comment: Я и пытаюсь с этим разобраться...

Comment: Значит, если я правильно понял, мне необходимо перекодировать строку с именем файла из utf-8 в utf-16 LE, и потом использовать_wfopen? Все остальное не меняется? Я имею в виду fclose(), fread(), fseek() и пр.

Comment: Да. По ссылке же [есть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx#Anchor_6) пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Как при помощи fopen() открывать файлы, имена которых содержат недопустимые символы?

Ни как, для gtk используй обёртку [`g_fopen()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-fopen) — она специально предназначен для того чтобы открывать файлы с именем в кодировке (обычно utf-8) возвращаемой `gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()` и другим glib'овскими/gtk'шными функциями.

> Как имена файлов представлены в Windows 10 на самом деле?

как и во всех версия начиная с 2000 — UTF16le.

> 3) Даже если вместо fopen() использовать Win API, CreateFile(), то могут быть проблемы с открытием файла, в имени/пути которого имеются недопустимые символы.

Да. Под win для полноценной поддержки интернационализации нужно использовать широкосимвольные версии (с суффиксом `W`) вызовов winAPI.